# I need to sort a LinkedList which will be displayed on a JList - java

Tags: java, sorting, jlist

I am making a calendar scheduling program. Right now, I have a JList with entries from my LinkedList. Is there a way to sort the LinkedList so that Sunday will appear first, and Saturday will appear last? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: Have a look at `Comparable` and `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Collections.sort()` will sort any list you pass to it. First sort the array list and then put it in the `JList`.